# Nodemailer options for Mailtrap ( Error: too many emails per second)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemailer

How should I configure options in nodemailer for mailtrap free version?  I get this error all the time no matter what I try:

"Error: Data command failed: 550 5.7.0 Requested action not taken: too many emails per second"

**Mailtrap free allows 2 message per 10 seconds.**

```
const sendMail = async (email, title) => {

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
    },
    pool: ??, 
    rateLimit: ??, 
    maxConnections: ??, 
    maxMessages: ?? 
  });

  const messageOptions = {
    from: 'xx xxxx <xxx.@xxx.com>',
    to: email,
    subject: title,
    text: `---text here---`
  };

  await transporter.sendMail(messageOptions);
};

module.exports = sendMail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mailtrap allows 5 mails per 10 seconds, so I tried

```
pool: true,
maxConnections: 1,
rateDelta: 10000,
rateLimit: 5,
```

But that didn't seem to work, so I increased the timer to 20 seconds

```
pool: true,
maxConnections: 1,
rateDelta: 20000,
rateLimit: 5,
```

This solution worked for me, I think it has something to do with the timer not being able to process the exact amount of 5 mails within 10 seconds.